# Creating a Custom Field Type with nested Fields

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I'm just wondering is it possible to have nested Fields inside of a Custom Field type.

So if I create a custom Field type. I wish for it to contain all of the following. So it will contain multiple fields inside of it.

- Asset
- Matrix
- Entry

Is this something that can be achieved.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Anderscc, please let us know if that post I liked to answers your question.

Comment: carlsc, I don't think that is the same as what I'm asking. That is to add an assets field. I want to add multiple fields inside of one custom field type. So they'd all be nested within the one. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: *"custom field types hold several different form input fields. For example the field may be called video and contain a title field, caption field, video slug field and a thumbnail field."* – sounds very similar to me

Comment: Dude, that is from the question. There is also no accepted answer on that question. Pointless linking that question.

Comment: Heh, so you’re saying that it is pointless to make you aware of a question basically asking the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need a new custom field type for this. What your describing has been accomplished quite well already by the **Neo** plugin...

> https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo

Additionally, the **Super Table** plugin has similar capabilities...

> https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable